# How allow copy/paste/cut in UIAlertView? (iOS, Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, copy-paste, uipasteboard

I want to allow users to copy/cut but mainly **PASTE** data from other apps into my app. I need to allow them to paste data in `UIAlertView`, when they are logging to the app. How can i make it?

**This is my code:**

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                message:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"enter_login", nil)]
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"


[alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];
[[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
[[alert textFieldAtIndex:1] becomeFirstResponder];
[UserDefaultsServices resetLoginCredentials];
[UserDefaultsServices resetLoginData];
self.alertView = alert;
[alert show];
```

It does this:
[show what my code does, I need to allow users to paste data in password TextField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCwcv.png)

Comment: Use UIAlertController, AlertView is/will be deprecated.

Comment: Don't use `UIALertView` it's deprecated and you can refer here for `UIAlertController` with textfields https://stackoverflow.com/a/33000328/5622566

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add TextField to UIAlertController in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922349/how-to-add-textfield-to-uialertcontroller-in-swift)

Comment: ++ in shared answer you just need to add `textField.isSecureTextEntry = true` for your password and I have checked copy/paste is working there.

Comment: @kamaldeepsinghbhatia hi, please, where exactly should be that line of code? ("textField.isSecureTextEntry = true")?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this answer](http://%20stackoverflow.com/a/33000328/5622566) for swift versions :

Objective C version of shared answer is :

```
- (IBAction)showAlert:(id)sender {
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Add New Name" message:@"Your message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField * _Nonnull textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"Name";
    }];

    [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField * _Nonnull textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"Password";
        textField.secureTextEntry = true;
    }];

    UIAlertAction *saveAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        // here you can access your textfields' texts
        NSString *textField1 = alertController.textFields[0].text;
        NSString *textField2 = alertController.textFields[1].text;
        NSLog(@"Saving %@ %@", textField1, textField2);
    }];

    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        // here you can access your textfields' texts
        NSString *textField1 = alertController.textFields[0].text;
        NSString *textField2 = alertController.textFields[1].text;
        NSLog(@"Canceled %@ %@", textField1, textField2);
    }];

    [alertController addAction:saveAction];
    [alertController addAction:cancelAction];

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Above code work like this :

[image: Copy/Paste Demo]

Comment: I still dont know how to make it :(

I copy code you sent me but it still doesnt work. Should I rename function on my "showLoginAlertViewWithTitle", right?

Comment: yes, you have to configure it according to your code. You need to add your actions (whatever you're doing with `ok` or `cancel`).

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesnt do anything. I renamed function, and I am calling it, but nothing appears. It cant be done easier? I just need to allow copy/paste for users, is it impossible to do that like with one command? :D

Comment: See.. It isn't difficult may be your code is breaking somewhere. Here I have attached the output also.

Comment: ouu! I really want this, but my code work like this  - https://imgur.com/a/9dRUfgI

Comment: Show your code where you're calling it and how you're using it. Your alert isn't showing here. Are you getting any error in logs?

Comment: inside `showLoginAlertViewWithTitle` you have added above code, right? I think you don't need `clickButtonAtIndex` here. your code for specific button should be placed inside the block.

Comment: even when I delete that function - clickedButtonIndex - your code still doesnt working, I dont know where could be mistake....Is it possible to use PasteBoard for paste date from other app?

Comment: Can I know where you're presenting this alert? I mean is it on an existing `viewController` or you're using it as standalone alert?

Comment: This Alert shows every-time, when user is logging. So user start App and then this alert shows. And I need, if user has some other app, for example lastpass where he copy password and then he want it to paste it in my app.

Comment: You need a `view controller` say `mainViewController` then in `viewDidAppear` you can call this alert OR you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35672915/5622566 for this you need to replace `self` in `[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];` with `rootcontroller` of app.

Comment: Related to copy paste, Yes you can use `PasteBoard` but it is also deprecated in iOS 10 and from then it'll be handled implicitly so I don't think you need this now

Comment: RootController is not working - it is showing me an error.

Comment: what will change if I change first row to this - "- (void) showLoginAlertViewWithTitle:(NSString *)title"

Comment: today I made some changes in code and now options  like - copy, cut and paste - are shown me. But when I click on paste or copy, nothing happens. It seems me, like that buttons are blocked or cant do what they should... Please do you know, what it could be?

Comment: Try viewHierarchy debugger to debug more... Not sure why it's happening. :|